# Is a Database Needed Behind My ASP Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access, asp.net-ajax

I am building a website Asp.Net/C# and one component has a schedule with the AJAX Calendar Extender that puts the selected date in a text box, of course. I also have an AJAX Time Picker pick a time in another box.

However, I'm feeling a little ambitious; I want it where if someone selects say... July 25th, 2014, at like 1:30 PM, I want it to throw back a message on selection that the block of time is already selected. The time intervals run every 15 mins apart (i.e., 1:00, 1:15, 1:30, and 1:45).

I'm thinking I need a database behind the site to hold this, maybe SQL Server or would a lightweight Access workup due? My though is that it will hit the database and check for a duplicate instance of the select date and time slot, chosen by the user - then report back if it gets a hit... otherwise, it will populate the date and time text fields in the form.

It's for a small yard service company that makes out calls, but I wanna test and push myself. Any advice and structure suggestions from some seasoned pros who would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Let me know if I need to provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a database holding the data, where will you store the booked time slot? Where you plan to store your login information like user acc/password.

Of course you can store into text file but I would suggest a light DB like access. It would be enough for you to store few tables with not many line of data.

I do not see any problem with your taught to verify the data again what you stored in db. It should be the way.

Comment: It won't have login information. It's a little site that just will allow customers to select dates and times for either requesting lawn care, or drop off a car for detailing. I have an email wired up that will receive the input information such as first name, last name, phone, city/zip, date, time, service option (checkbox list), and comments (textarea). The email message will be formatted. I just wanna know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do, and have the application spit back info when someone selects a similar time on the "same date," prior to the user hitting the submit button.

Comment: after user hitting summit button, where all these info(first name, last name, phone, city/zip, date, time) goes to ? It should be into a database right? Maybe a table call Appointment?

there is 2 way after user hit the submit button, either through frontend ajax for better user experience or a postback on the button click event